# Spring-Boot: Thymeleaf layouts not resolved for nested urls

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf layouts are resolved and works fine for simple urls.
Ex: www.abc.com/users

However, that's not the case for nested urls
Ex: www.abc.com/advisor/building

I am not sure if this is a thymeleaf or spring-boot issue.

Here is my layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title layout:title-pattern="$DECORATOR_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">My App</title>      
</head>

<body>

<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"></div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="pageContent">

        <div layout:fragment="content"></div>

    </div>
</div>

<div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the content that is supposed to be decorated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorator="layouts/default">

<head>
    <title>General Building</title>
</head>

<div layout:fragment="content">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>

</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with more details?

Comment: I edited the question to give more details.

Comment: get you a request in your controller? (would the RequestMapping-Method be called?)

Comment: Yes, the request is handled and page is displayed, but without the decoration, so header and footer do not show up.

Comment: This turned out to be a non-issue. I guess a library conflict or something caused this. After rebuilding my project, the issue went away.